# Broken xorg.conf file

Tags: 12.04, xorg, restore

If I break the xorg.conf file and I can't startup Ubuntu 12.04.  How do I revert back to a backup xorg.conf file called xorg.conf.backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

1. I had to boot into safe mode
2. Click on the root command line option
3. At the command line I typed: `fsck` to get the disk mount path
4. Mounted the disk using the command `mount -o remount <mount path from fsck goes here>`
5. Then I used `cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak /etc/X11/xorg.conf` to restore the backup

Answer (score 2):

you can restore it normally by booting to the recovery mode then coping over the other file

`cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

then restart and it should load the new xorg.conf

if it just boots to the shell you should be able to do this but you will need to use sudo.

Comment: I tried that but I got a message saying that it's read-only.  I used sudo too.